# Throttling requests on AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-ndb

My service sends messages to users, and I want to throttle on the following criteria; Saying a user A belongs to group G.

1. max 5 messages within last hour to user A
2. max 100 messages with last hour to members belong to group A

The number of messages and floating window size are configurable.

Any recommended options?

- Is Cloud Endpoints an option?
- Apigee is too expensive for our service.

More Background:

- use app engine standard environment python2.7
- the request is internal; a app engine service send request to another app engine service

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [API Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/get-started-frameworks-python) with App Engine instead of Apigee or Cloud Endpoints [API Gateway quotas](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/quotas-overview), it provides support for Python 2.7 and supports quotas like the ones you need.